# How to make array elements moveable at different speeds?

Tags: c#

I'm trying to code a kind of simple car game in C# console and there is a X in screen that is trying to reach across the road. I wrote the cars into a array randomly.

```
char[] road1 = { '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-'...}
while(true)
{
    for (i = 0; i < 50; i++)
        Console.Write(road1[i]);
    for (int j = 1; j < 50; j++) 
    {
        (road1[j - 1], road1[j]) = (road1[j], road1[j - 1]);
    }      

    Thread.Sleep(50);
}
```

I made the cars moveable in the nested for loop but the movement is always at a constant speed. How do I make the nested for loop move in variable speed?

Comment: Calculate the next location based on the "speed".  If the speed is 1 cell per tick, change the location by 1. If 2, 2 etc.

Comment: Please re-phrase the question the last statement. Are you trying to ask - I made the cars moveable in the nested for loop but the movement is always at a constant speed. How do I make the nested for loop move in variable speed? If so please edit the question with this text.

Comment: `var road1 = (new string('-', 80)).ToCharArray();`

Comment: Also `var road1 = Enumerable.Repeat('-', 80).ToArray();`